# How to refresh/access model from a JSP

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp

Can someone please let me know how to access a Model from a JSP.

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/systemById", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getSystemById(Model model, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
     model.addAttribute("fSystemName", "Test name");
     name = system.getName();
}
```

JSP code:

```
$('#uINewsSystemList').change(function() {
    $.get("/application/systemById");
);  

<form:form id="systemForm" commandName="systemForm">
<tr>
    <td valign="top"><form:input path="fSystemName" value="${fSystemName}" size="20" />&nbsp;</td>                      
</tr>
```

I cant get the form to refresh once i've added the string to the model. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do exactly? Is your JSP the view associated to the controller? Do you want to update the form dynamically once `#uINewsSystemList` is changed?

Comment: Yes, once they select an item from uINewsSystemList it should change the values in the form appropriately. And yes the JSP is the view associated with the controller

Answer (score 3):

When you make an ajax call based on user interaction the flow you are invoking has nothing to do with the original JSP you used to render the page.

You can either have the getSystemById method totally re-render the page (probably via form submit/POST) or you can alter your example code to actually return the necessary data to make the changes via JavaScript. Since you mentioned you are looking for dynamic updating the changes could look something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/systemById/${id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getSystemById(@PathVariable String id) throws IOException {
     //lookup new system data by id
     Model model = someService.getModelById(id);
     return model.getName(); //you can return more than just name, but then you will need some sort of conversion to handle that data (json, xml, etc.)
}
```

The client ajax call will need to be setup to have a success function where you use the returned data to update the ui.

```
$('#uINewsSystemList').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.get("/application/systemById/" + id, function(returnedData){
        //use returnedData to refresh the ui.
        $('selectorForSystemNameField').val(returnedData);
    });
);
```

Comment: If your controller is already setup to expect Strings as view names you will also need the @ResponseBody annotation on getSystemById method.